# Element p not allowed as child of element h2 in this context

Tags: html

My HTML code is

```
<h2><p><strong>My text</strong></p></h2>
```

This throws the error `Element p not allowed as child of element h2 in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)`

I've tried multiple cominations but all seem to be throwing an error. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: <p><h2><strong>My text </strong></h2></p> try this

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh Nope doesn't work. This gives `No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.` error

Comment: what you are trying to do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot put paragraphs inside a heading.

[From the HTML standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements), only "phrasing content" is allowed inside of a heading element (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6). The [definition of "phrasing content"](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#phrasing-content) is:

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing content form paragraphs.
>
> `a` `abbr` `area` (if it is a descendant of a map element) `audio` `b` `bdi` `bdo` `br` `button` `canvas` `cite` `code` `data` `datalist` `del` `dfn` `em` `embed` `i` `iframe` `img` `input` `ins` `kbd` `keygen` `label` `link` (if the `itemprop` attribute is present) `map` `mark` `math` `meta` (if the `itemprop` attribute is present) `meter` `noscript` `object` `output` `progress` `q` `ruby` `s` `samp` `script` `select` `small` `span` `strong` `sub` `sup` `svg` `template` `textarea` `time` `u` `var` `video` `wbr` text
>
> Most elements that are categorized as phrasing content can only contain elements that are themselves categorized as phrasing content, not any flow content.

You shouldn't need to put paragraphs inside headings since headings are supposed to describe the paragraphs that follow it (like in a newspaper or magazine). If you need to increase the spacing then use the `margin` property in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `<p>` and `</p>` tags. A `p` element is not valid inside a `h2` and would make no sense there.

Consider also dropping the `<strong>` and `</strong>`, whatever they are meant to cause. A heading such as `h2` is by its nature an emphatic part of a document, and it is also displayed in bold face by default. Suitable markup would thus be

```
<h2>My text</h2>
```